# Radio buttons subtract from total when checked

Tags: javascript, radio-button

I'm just starting to learn how to use javascript and it is my first language. 
What I'm trying to do is have each radio button subtract an amount from the input amount. Right now it is only works for 1 radio button. If I click 2 it just subtracts from the bottom one.

```html
<!doctype html>

<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Numbers Test</title>
</head>

<body>
  <form name="operation_form">
    <label>Verify</label>
    <br/>
    <label>Acert Score:</label><input type="number" name='acertscore' />
    <br/>
    <input type="radio" name="rad1" id="rad1" value='-100' />100
    <br/>
    <input type="radio" name="rad2" id="rad2" value='-200' />200
    <br/>
    <input type="radio" name="rad3" id="rad3" value='-250' />250
    <br/>
    <input type="button" value="Calculate" onclick="operationForm();" />
    <br/>
    <label>Score total is:</label><input type="text" name="answerbox">
    <br/>
    <input type="button" value="Reset" onClick="this.form.reset()" />
  </form>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    function operationForm() {
      var form = document.forms["operation_form"];
    
      var x = form["acertscore"].value;
    
      var operation = null;
      var answer = null;
    
      if (form["rad1"].checked == true) {
        answer = x - 100;
      }
      if (form["rad2"].checked == true) {
        answer = x - 200;
      }
      if (form["rad3"].checked == true) {
        answer = x - 250;
      }
    
      form["answerbox"].value = answer;
    }
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

I'm sure I'm going at this the wrong way. If there is an easier way I would love to learn it.

Comment: Someone posted the answer but deleted their comment.var answer = x;
    
      if (form["rad1"].checked == true) {
        answer = answer - 100;
      }
      if (form["rad2"].checked == true) {
        answer = answer - 200;
      }
      if (form["rad3"].checked == true) {
        answer = answer - 250;
      }

Answer (score 2):

You're setting the answer to the Acert Score minus the radio button's value every time you happen upon a checked form input, effectively overwriting it each time.

Also - is there any reason you are using radio buttons as opposed to checkboxes? You wouldn't have to have a reset button on the form.

```html
<!doctype html>

<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Numbers Test</title>
</head>

<body>
  <form name="operation_form">
    <label>Verify</label>
    <br/>
    <label>Acert Score:</label><input type="number" name='acertscore' />
    <br/>
    <input type="checkbox" name="rad1" id="rad1" value='-100' />100
    <br/>
    <input type="checkbox" name="rad2" id="rad2" value='-200' />200
    <br/>
    <input type="checkbox" name="rad3" id="rad3" value='-250' />250
    <br/>
    <input type="button" value="Calculate" onclick="operationForm();" />
    <br/>
    <label>Score total is:</label><input type="text" name="answerbox">
    <br/>
    <input type="button" value="Reset" onClick="this.form.reset()" />
  </form>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    function operationForm() {
      var form = document.forms["operation_form"];
    
      var x = form["acertscore"].value;
    
      var operation = null;
      var answer = null;
    
      if (form["rad1"].checked === true) {
        x -= 100;
      }
      if (form["rad2"].checked === true) {
        x -= 200;
      }
      if (form["rad3"].checked === true) {
        x -= 250;
      }

      answer = x;
    
      form["answerbox"].value = answer;
    }
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

When multiple buttons are checked, multiple if loops also execute. In the case of the `100` and the `200` radio button checked, both of these if statements execute:

```
if (form["rad1"].checked == true) {
    answer = x - 100;
}
if (form["rad2"].checked == true) {
    answer = x - 200;
}
```

After the first if statement, `answer` will equal `x - 100`. However, since the `200` radio button is also checked, `answer` will be overwritten with `x - 200` and giving you the results you're seeing.

**Solution**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function operationForm() {
        var form = document.forms["operation_form"];

        var x = form["acertscore"].value;

        var operation = null;

        // set answer equal to what is in the input box OR zero if it's empty 
        // (since x would be undefined in that case)
        var answer = x || 0; 

        if (form["rad1"].checked == true) {
            answer = answer - 100;
        }
        if (form["rad2"].checked == true) {
            answer = answer - 200;
        }
        if (form["rad3"].checked == true) {
            answer = answer - 250;
        }

        form["answerbox"].value = answer;
    }
</script>
```